# How to update the different XML element simultaneously by multiple users in single XML file?

Tags: c#, xml

I have one XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"                                     <xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
 <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="UsersPreferenceSettingsDT">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="USERPROFILEID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="SCREENAMEID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="FREEZEDCOLUMNID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="ORDEROFCOLUMNS" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
<UsersPreferenceSettingsDT>
  <USERPROFILEID>219</USERPROFILEID>
  <SCREENAMEID>1</SCREENAMEID>
  <FREEZEDCOLUMNID>2|3|4|5</FREEZEDCOLUMNID>
  <ORDEROFCOLUMNS>1</ORDEROFCOLUMNS>
</UsersPreferenceSettingsDT>
<UsersPreferenceSettingsDT>
  <USERPROFILEID>123</USERPROFILEID>
  <SCREENAMEID></SCREENAMEID>
  <FREEZEDCOLUMNID>s|s|s</FREEZEDCOLUMNID>
  <ORDEROFCOLUMNS></ORDEROFCOLUMNS>
</UsersPreferenceSettingsDT>
</NewDataSet>
```

In that i have to update the XML Element (i,e USERPROFILeID =219, USERPROFILEID is Unique). At same time another user also update the same XML file but different XML element (i,e USERPROFILEID=123). How can the XML reflect the both users XML update(Like SQL or ORACLE DB Update). I used the following code to update.

```
userPreferenceSettingsDS.WriteXml(userPreferenceSettingsXMLFilePath, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

but it reflect the last user profile update Value only , while multiple user simultaneously update the XML. Anyone guide me to come out of these issue?

Comment: If multiple users from multiple machines can all access the file at once, you are going to have issues with concurrency; it's not as simple as always loading the latest version of the file before save, as you don't know if someone else is doing this at the same time as you, for example. You can mitigate this by directing all reads and writes to a central component used by all clients, but then you are effectively writing a database...

Answer (score 1):

Well, being that we are talking about an xml file and not a database you will not be able to get the "latest" version of the data unless you always load from file and not from memory but even then you expose yourself to concurrency issues.

The best choice here would be to switch to a database or maybe implement something like a Singleton Repository that would serve all users and that way you will always return the latest values of the data in the xml.

And it would fix your other issue, when you write to file you will write the "merged" version of the data that will contain changes from multiple users.

---

Resources for XML as database:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldataaccess/thread/346a2816-faae-461d-aaa8-235d9c0dd55c

[XML Database in C#.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635175/xml-database-in-c-net)

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/460625-c-pure-xml-database

Comment: ya i tried load from file option also . that also update whole XML file only. Not updating the Particular element. (FYR :  by using xmldocument.Save()). This also update the whole document which is last fetched from the file(not from the memory). I heard that XML file is using as as database. How they can handling this type of issue?

Comment: Check the links i just added to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Or use a single profile file per user.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to ensure that only one save operation can happen at a time.

To do this, you need to provide a static (shared) class that reads from and writes to the file. The fancy new buzzword for this is a Singleton instance, but it's simply the following:

```
public static class MyXMLAccessor
{
    public static void saveTheData()
    {
        //this method would write the data to the XML file and save it.
    }

    public static string ReadTheData()
    {
        //to read the data from the file
    }
}
```

This way, you're guaranteed that the result of one operation is saved before the next operation is started.

A more complex solution would be to read the xml into an application-scope dataset so that it can act like a database. You would then periodically write the contents of the dataset back to a file using the DataSet.ToXML() method.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me as if you should be using an XML database. The sooner you make the move, the more benefit you will get from it, and the less you will spend on creating your own inadequate home-grown solution.